# Professional orbital simulation software methods, accuracy, runtime

Tags: iterative-method, simulation

I'm working on an orbital body simulation as a personal project. I understand that it's not going to be as good as professional software, but I'm wondering what contemporary,
general purpose, iterative, professional software looks like. What kind of methods are used? How accurate are they? What kind of runtime efficiency is expected? Are Newtonian methods even used anymore, or do they all use relativistic methods?

Comment: What is the aim of the simulation? Satellites in Earth orbit with all the lumpy contributions to the gravity field? The main parts of the Solar system, or with all the moons and asteroids and dust belts and ...? Would that not be more specific on space.SE or astronomy.SE, see for instance https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/43314/how-significant-is-orbit-propagator-choice and links therein,

Comment: It's a general purpose simulation, designed to handle any size bodies, including those of the main solar system. It doesn't have any J2 perturbation implemented, or other lumpy contributions. Will this likely be my largest source of error for satellites in LEO? Or should I expect larger errors from using a simple verlet integration? Should I focus on handling the lumpy contributions or improving my integral approximation?